# android carrying text form one class to a alertdialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, alert, android-alertdialog

i want to carry text from a edittext in one class to another class that displays a alert dialog.
i want to take the edittext name input and put it in the alert dialog message.

```
public class forum extends Activity {

EditText name, place;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    place = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.place);
```

second class

```
public class AlertDemo extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Turn Screen On and Unlock the keypad when this alert dialog is displayed */
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

    /** Creating a alert dialog builder */
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    /** Setting title for the alert dialog */
    builder.setTitle("alert");

    /** Setting the content for the alert dialog */
    builder.setMessage("alerting");

    /** Defining an OK button event listener */
    builder.setPositiveButton("alert", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            /** Exit application on click OK */
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    /** Creating the alert dialog window */
    return builder.create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DialogFragment.setArguments & getArguments method

sample code as below,

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/place"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/place"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Place" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/place"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="ShowAlertDemo"
        android:onClick="buttonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText name, place;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        place = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.place);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
          button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    String nameText = name.getText().toString();
                    String placeText = place.getText().toString();

                    AlertDemo a = new AlertDemo();


                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString("nameText", nameText);
                    args.putString("placeText", nameText);

                    a.setArguments(args);

                     a.show(getFragmentManager(), "Confirm");
                 }
             });
    }


}
```

AlertDemo.java

```
package com.example.test;


import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams;


public class AlertDemo extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /** Turn Screen On and Unlock the keypad when this alert dialog is displayed */
    getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

    /**
     * Code to retreive values
     */
    String name = getArguments().getString("nameText");
    String place = getArguments().getString("placeText");

    /** Creating a alert dialog builder */
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    /** Setting title for the alert dialog */
    builder.setTitle("alert");

    /** Setting the content for the alert dialog */
    builder.setMessage("alerting Name:"+name+"  Place:"+place);

    /** Defining an OK button event listener */
    builder.setPositiveButton("alert", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            /** Exit application on click OK */
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    /** Creating the alert dialog window */
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Result

[image]

Enter the text in the text box and click on the button
[image]

Text is transferred from MainActivity to the Alert 
[image]